# Prove $I(\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{C}^3: x^2+y^2+z^2-1=0\}) = (x^2+y^2+z^2-1)\mathbb{C}[x,y,z] $

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I got stuck in proving that $$I(\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{C}^3: x^2+y^2+z^2-1=0\}) = (x^2+y^2+z^2-1)\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]. $$

Let $X= \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{C}^3: x^2+y^2+z^2-1=0\}$, and $I(X) = \{ f \in \mathbb{C} [x,y,z]: f(P)=0 , \ \forall P \in X \}$.
I would like to check that
$$I(X) = (x^2+y^2+z^2-1)\mathbb{C}[x,y,z] .$$

My attempt:

For ($\supset$), it is clear.

For ($\subset$), for any $P \in I(X)$ and $f \in X$, we have $f(P)=0$.

Then $f$ can be written by $(x^2+y^2+z^2-1)h(x,y,z)$. Hence, $f \in (x^2+y^2+z^2-1)\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$.

I think it quite wrong.

Could you please give me any idea to check this problem.

Thank in advance.

Comment: I would suggest searching on the term, Nullstellensatz.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you for your help. Could you please help me check that: Let $J= (x^2+y^2+z^2-1)\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$, so $X \supset V(J)$. Then for $f \in I(X)$, there is $r$ such that $f^r \in J=(x^2+y^2+z^2-1)\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$. How can I obtain that $r=1$?